# Не работают подсказки в библиотеке OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Установил библиотеку OpenCV (через pip) и импортировал её, библиотека работает, но по какой-то причине не отображаются подсказки, кто-нибудь знает как решить?

Пытался найти ответ в интернетах, и вроде нашёл, но ничего не понял (https://russianblogs.com/article/10161305662/).

Python 3.10 / PyCharm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: балин, забыл скриншот прикрепить, обновил))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл решение методом тыка, нужно в интерпретаторы добавить путь до папки cv2 в site-packages

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]